# Can "xsl:include" be used to build a correct HTML Document tree, assuming the HTML childs are in "xsl:include" file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I am preparing to auto-produce some 2.500 lines of XHTML and am using XSLT to transform XML/XSL to an output XHTML file. Due to the length (and also to get better overview) I am looking to modularize the XSL.

According to the XSL2.0 Spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#include, include must me a top-level element which mean I cannot add the include tag inside another template.

**To clarify my question:**

In this specific case, is it possible to use "xsl:include", as part of building together the HTML tag structure, where HTML is parent, head and body are childs, etc.?

Note! I am fully aware that I am missing the HTML tag when performing the "include" scenario,
but that's because I don't know how to add the HTML tag in order to solve the HTML structure.

---

I have searched in the XSL specification, Saxon documentation as well as other channels to find examples of performing XSLT, together with "xsl:include" in order to modularize the code, without success.

**XML file(used for both test scenarios):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="stylesheet.xsl" version="2.0"?>

<data>
  <repo-1>
    <title>Title-1</title>
    <title>Title-2</title>
  </repo-1>
  <repo-2>
  <body>Body content from XML data</body>
</repo-2>
</data>
```

**XSL file when using only one XSL without includes**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
  <xsl:template match="/data">

  <html>
    <head>
      <title>
        <xsl:value-of select = "repo-1/title[2]"/>
    </title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <xsl:value-of select = "repo-2/body"/>
    </body>
  </html>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**My XSL with includes**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!-- Includes -->
<xsl:include href="head.xsl"></xsl:include>
<xsl:include href="body.xsl"></xsl:include>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

**XSL include file [head]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/data/repo-1">
      <head>
        <title>
          <xsl:value-of select = "title"/>
        </title>
      </head>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSL include file [body]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/data/repo-2">
      <body>
        <xsl:value-of select = "body"/>
      </body>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result from using one XSL file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Title-2</title>
</head>

<body>Body content from XML data</body>
```

**Result from using includes:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<head>
  <title>Title-1 Title-2</title>
</head>

<body>Body content from XML data</body>

</html>
```

**Wanted result from using includes**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Title-2</title>
</head>

<body>Body content from XML data</body>
```

Comment: `<xsl:include>` is just an instruction allowing you to merge stylesheet modules together. Your problem comes from the two `<title>` element nested in `/data/repo-1`, thus using `<xsl:value-of select = "title[2]"/>` should solve your issue. Note, when generating HTML, consider adding an `<xsl:output method="xhtml"/>` at the beginning of your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<xsl:template match="/data">

  <html>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </html>

</xsl:template>
```

in the main stylesheet that includes the two modules.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a little unusual, but you could use XInclude to insert code into a stylesheet (you would need to put it through an XInclude processor before submitting it to the XSLT processor). That's one of the benefits of XSLT being XML - you can use the whole XML processing apparatus on your stylesheet code.

I think the reason this isn't done often is that it doesn't encourage the right kind of modularity and reusability of code that you get using xsl:include and xsl:import.